# Connect WP8 (VM) with node.js server using TCP

Tags: node.js, sockets, windows-phone-8, sails.js, netduino

I'm working on a school project. The goal is to link a Windows Phone 8 (WP8) with a server (node.js using sails.js framework based on express.js) by TCP socket.

I have found a great tutorial for the C# part (WP8), I'm working with a Windows 8 Virtual Machine but it's not an issue. (Just slow an borring -_-)

Based on the tutorial, I "realized" the WP part. I realized also the node.js server, using socket.io.

Here the WP8 tutorial: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202858(v=vs.105).aspx

Here my WP8 application (8.0): (Based on the tutorial but customized)

SocketClient: http://pastebin.com/8ncad4EV

MainPage.cs: http://pastebin.com/5VAU96JV

Mainpage.xaml.cs: http://pastebin.com/hhvmQvPS

Here, a screenshot of the application + node.js server side source code: [image: WP8 and node server]

On the left screen you can see the server side code which create "listeners". At right the VM with WP8 and the emulator.
As you can see, I can connect to my server using socket. But I don't get any response.

About server logs, there is no log created when I run the WP8 application, it's writted than the connection is a success but no log on the server about it.

You can see the website directly here: 137.135.176.144:1337 and you can use the javascript console for run tests if you want, like:

```
socket.emit('disconnection', function(res){console.log(res);});
```

You will see a response from the server about you are disconnected (it's just a log, not true) and I will get it on my own console, server side.

But when I try to connect with WP8 or netduino (because I have to connect netuido and WP8 using sockets with node.js) it's the same. No error during connection but no response.

So, I'm here because I'm noobie about node.js and I tried a lot of things but still the same. Could you help me? Thank you.

---

I'm trying something else. Another code client side (WP8).
Because I was running synchronious requests, I'm trying to run asynchronious now, because the node.js server is asynchrone:

[Source code](http://pastebin.com/XE2JTkGm)

*You can create a new project, add this class and call it in the "main" function.*

**Output**:

```
Application proccessing...
Application started
Operation processing: Connect
Connect: Successful connection etablished to Unspecified/137.135.176.144:1337
Operation processing: Send
Operation processing: Receive
Data received: connection (10)
```

Date received is equal to the data I sent myself (you can see it line 70). I don't get data from the server (Or I do it wrong) and I don't see any connection on the server console.

As you can see I'm not sure to call the good URL, but if I write *http://* before the IP address, the program throw a SocketException: **"No such host is known"**

```
An exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll and wasn't handled before a managed/native boundary
An exception of type 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' occurred in System.Net.ni.dll and wasn't handled before a managed/native boundary
An exception of type 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' occurred in System.Net.ni.dll and wasn't handled before a managed/native boundary
A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' occurred in SocketsTest.DLL
```

I don't understand why it throw an error with *http://*.
The source code server side is the same than before.

Could you help me? I'm pretty lost here.
Thank you.

Comment: i have no great knowledge on c# , but `socket.io` client doesn't seem to be `socket.io` compactible.. you should really use some of the client from socket.io wiki https://github.com/LearnBoost/Socket.IO/wiki, remember `socket.io` its not TCP its Websockets

Comment: Yeah. Probably, thank you I'm looking for a solution probably use socket.io server side and no websocket.
I took a look of your link but there is nothing useful for me, I'm working with C# and the only one available works only for 4.0 .NET. https://socketio4net.codeplex.com/

Comment: well on other side, wp8 programming is done with javascript, tried to include `socket.io-client` in javascript?

Comment: I read somewhere that I could use a frame with a kind of browser inside in WP and by this way I could use the website directly.
But, I have another issue, I need to connect with the netduino, using socket.io or websocket, but websocket don't really exists in .NETMF...

Comment: A friend just told me that sails.js used socket.io, not websocket. And it's probably true because the script client side is named socket.io.js ^^ So... it's because of something else, maybe? I want to ask to the staff/support but not answer yet.

Comment: Have you read over the Socket.io protocol doc at https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io-spec?  Are you performing the Socket.io handshake when you first connect, to get the session ID, and are you sending your requests to the correct URI (http://137.135.176.144:1337/socket.io/1/websocket/[session id]) ?

Comment: I didn't knew all these things, but after read the documentation, it works with direct http. But I can't use it with my phone/netduino (.NET C#) it's a TCP connection which is required, with this kind of source code (WP8) http://pastebin.com/5VAU96JV

I have a request timeout from the phone, using TCP connection and following this tutorial: http://www.sebastianseilund.com/json-socket-sending-json-over-tcp-in-node.js-using-sockets

I can only choose the host and the port, nothing else, so I can't get the id or something, it's not the good way... I don't understand. Thank you for help.

Comment: Read about specification doesn't helped me. But it was interesting. Anyway, it's not the good way I thing, because I can't call this kind of URL using .NET native objects/methods...