# Sails.js - Choose between websocket or socket.io

Tags: windows-phone-8, websocket, socket.io, sails.js, netduino

I want to use socket.io instead of websocket with sails.js framework.

I know I saw something about that two days ago but I don't remember where...

Do you know where can I choose between both? Because my client is WP8/Netduino and can only use socket.io protocol, not the websocket.

Thank you.

Comment: Vadorequest, I'm about to publish a screencast going over how to use socket.io in sails.  In the meantime I have this screencasts which is a prequel to the upcoming episode http://irlnathan.github.io/sailscasts/blog/2013/09/06/building-a-sails-application-ep18-understanding-web-sockets-and-socket-io-including-room-creation-and-management/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sails.js [uses socket.io](http://sailsjs.org/?documentation/#!documentation/sockets), which, in it's turn, uses WebSocket as one of it's preferred transports, if it's available.

Comment: It's what I thought, about sails.js. Do you know how can I be sure to use socket.io? But honnestly I don't know why I can't receive anything... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19103993/connect-wp8-vm-with-node-js-server-using-tcp